# $A = \{(x, y): y = \sin \frac1x , 0 < x \leq 1\}$. Show that $\operatorname{cl}(A) = A \cup \{(0, y) : -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X = \Bbb{C}$ with the usual metric and $A = \{(x, y): y = \sin \frac1x , 0 < x \leq 1\}$. Show that $\operatorname{cl}(A) = A \cup \{(0, y) : -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$.

$\operatorname{cl}(A)$ contains $A$, But how is the second part coming.

Answer (score 0):

Put $B:=\{(0,y):-1\leq y\leq 1\}$. The set $A\cup B$ is called the **Topologist's sine curve**. It is one of the simplest example of a connected set that is not path connected.

First, $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ also contains $B$.

To see this, let $(x,y)\in B$ and $z>0$ such that $\sin z=y$. The sequence of points in $A$ given by $\left(\frac{1}{z+2n\pi},y\right)$ converges to $(x,y)$, hence $(x,y)\in A'\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A)$.

Now, you need to show that $\operatorname{cl}(A)\subseteq A\cup B$.

Let $(x,y)\in\operatorname{cl}(A)$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ of points in $A$ converging to $(x,y)$.

If $x>0$, then by continuity of $x\mapsto \sin 1/x$ we have $y=\sin 1/x$, so $(x,y)\in A$.

If $x=0$, since $|y_n|<1$, we have $|y|<1$ and hence $(x,y)\in B$.